# iOS - UITableView inside a horizontal CollectionView, horizontal collectionView in VerticalScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have worked on this problem from thress days ago. How could I make tableView scroll naturally after scrollView scrolled to its content bottom just like there is only one scrollView? I found a similar app named "闲鱼" perfectly solve this problem but don't know how. [View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fZpi.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about add UITableView's header view?
The part you want to show in the scroll view's upper side make as tableview's header view.

Comment: Not that simple, there may be multiple tableViews in a horizontal scroll collectionView and this collectionView is the subView of outside scrollView...thank you for your answer